# Two jQuery functions with one event

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to execute this Wordpress-Elementor function:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event ) {
        elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( {}, event );
    } );
```

within this event/function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// detects the start of an ajax request being made
$(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function(){
        $.LoadingOverlay("show", {
        background : "#183A4DED",
        imageColor : "#E9E071"

    });
        
});
```

which is triggered by a "Search&Filter Pro" AJAX Search event. With this event a spinner with overlay is initialized ( is working ) and an Elementor popup shall be closed.

I am new to javascript. Any answer is welcome!

Comment: This might help you: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/#:~:text=trigger(%20%22click%22%20)%3B,object%20passed%20into%20the%20event.  `$('.close-popup').trigger('click');`

Comment: Thx. This works for me: $('.close-popup').trigger('sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter"');

Answer (score 0):

This works:`$('.close-popup').trigger('sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter"');`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).